# Report Preview not displaying data

Tags: telerik-reporting

Need help on this as I'm quite new to using this Telerik Reporting tool.

I've configured my data source to point to the correct database and I've already set the query to be used to display the report. As you can see below, the data is shown in the preview data source result.
[image]

However when I preview it in the report designer, it is not showing any report data as seen below.
[image]

I need help on what to do in order to display the records in the report. I'm not sure where to check.

Comment: In the second image, you're using a different 'Trading Day To' value than what is in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

For company/Location you need to send ID=126 not name in preview window, same as in data source query.